# Excel Extraction, taking out three numeric characters in a string

Tags: excel

I am looking to find an excel formula or VB formula which would be able to extract specific data in excel.

For example we have the following in a cell: 
Time spent in `script:333`

The above will always remain the same, however the time will be different and can range from 1 to 999 so 3 numeric characters max. However.. In some cells there maybe changes after the 3 characters and may come out like so:
Time spent in `script:333Q1`

So I need a formula which extracts 3 numeric characters after the semi colon but to ignore anything after the 3 characters.

Comment: You say `semi colon` which is `;` I see `:` a colon

Answer (score 2):

Quite lengthy, but should help you,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,99),3))),VALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,99),3)),IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,99),2))),VALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,99),2)),VALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,99),1))))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works, however when I have: Time Spent in script:502Q1 it only brings back 50. However I need to pull through a maximum 3 values

Comment: @SQLeon does your values actually have a space between the `:` and the first number?

Answer (score -1):

A1 being the cell you're referencing...

`=MID(A1,22,3)`

EDIT: Now works for digits 1-999

`=IF(LEN(A1) = 26, MID(A1,22,3), IF(LEN(A1) = 25, MID(A1,22,2), IF(LEN(A1) = 24, MID(A1,22,1), "NA")))`

Comment: Does the number start always at position 22?

Comment: According to OP it does. But I forgot to account for the number being 1-3 digits long - will have to fix.

Comment: Eh, I misread the initial question... It looks like Gowtham has provided a viable solution for you :)